# Correct way to manage lookup tables/repeatable data/normalizing data

Tags: android, sql

I am in the process of building a database helper and provider and am stuck at best practice on the following.

Say I have a message to be delivered, it can have a status of "Pending","Sending","Sent","Delivered","Failed" and the database will keep track of each message and its current status.

My initial layout would be to have a "message_status_type" table and put all of the different statuses into this table. Then create a foreign key to the "messages" table to track the current status of the message and essentially normalize the database.

Now with android is this the best way to do it? Or is there a reason to not normalize simply store the message_status_type(s) as an integer in the message table and have a lookup in the provider or contract to translate the ID to a text value?

Or is it best practice to keep a separate table and let the provider merge the data to abstract the fact there is a "message_status_type" table?

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you're planning on using the database as a message queue: you should Google and understand the drawbacks before proceeding. I've done this before and it's never been a problem but there can be problems with locking in high-throughput scenarios.

I personally prefer to have a separate table with a foreign key constraint: it insures that all messages will be of the types that you expect and anyone can look in the database and see the message types. My message type table has typically contained a description of each type, which you can use for the display label in case I18n is not a concern. There are costs: any insert into the message table will need to validate that the message type satisfies the FKC. Also, any time that you need to add a new message type you'll need to update the database with the new type which can be a nuisance if you have dev/prod instances to maintain.

Comment: I have moved forward using a message_type table separated from the message table. But there will never be a high-throughput scenario. I would  expect average use to be about 2 outgoing at any one time. Perhaps an extreme case would be 20 or more. There is a thread that manages the message delivery, and it will simply update the message table so that the UI can show the status of the outgoing message. As well as providing legacy information regarding the transmitted message. If l18n is a concern would one store a resource_id? Or string value to match a resource lookup ?

Comment: If I18n is a concern, you're probably storing all user-visible strings in an external file per locale. You would just store the identifier in the database and there's not really any use to storing the string in the db except for developer understanding